# Underscorejs filter on collection of object 2 levels deep

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a an array of objects, that contains and array of objects, that contains an array of objects.

What I want to do is to filter on a property in the last array of objects.

Here is an example dataset

```
    var sampleData=[
   {
      "name":"Cooking",
      "shelve":[
         {
            "name":"Shelve 1",
            "drawers":[
               {                  
                  "Name":"Left"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Middle"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Shelve 2",
            "drawers":[
               {
                  "Name":"Middle side"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Left"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Up"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"DBs",
      "shelves":[
         {
            "name":"Shelve 3",
            "drawers":[
               {
                  "Name":"asdfasdf"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"New Test 12"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

Basically what I would like to do is to be able to get back the objects where drawer.name contains a substring.  I would like for it to return the full object graph so if I searched for Middle I would expect to get back

```
var sampleData=[
   {
      "name":"Cooking",
      "shelve":[
         {
            "name":"Shelve 1",
            "drawers":[
               {
                  "Name":"Middle"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Shelve 2",
            "drawers":[
               {
                  "Name":"Middle side"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

I was hoping that using underscore would help and I initially just tried to nest filters but that did not work.

I tried the following and while found would evaluate to true when it should it would not filter as I hoped.

```
var secs = _.filter(sampleData, function(section) {
                _.filter(section.shelve, function(shelve) {
                    _.filter(shelve.drawers, function(drawer) {
                        var found = drawer.Name.indexOf('Middle') !== -1;
                        if(found) {
                            var xa = 'found it!!';
                        }
                        return drawer.Name.indexOf('Middle') !== -1;
                    });
                }); 
            });
```

Here is a quick jsfiddler example. http://jsfiddle.net/cnalk/GtfNj/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, a basic array filter like `_.filter` doesn't provide a way to do two-step filtering (first, by values of an array; then by how many values passed), so you need to write your own filter function for each layer, such as:

```
function filter_shelf( shelf ) {

    var filtered = _.omit( shelf, 'drawers' );

    filtered.drawers = _.filter( shelf.drawers, filter_drawer );

    return filtered.drawers.length && filtered;

}
```

Complete fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/GtfNj/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/GtfNj/4/)

Each step considers the property it needs to filter, filters it by the step "below" it, then returns a filtered copy of itself or `false` if the property ended up empty from the filter. The step "above" it then filters based on that result. And so on...

Ps. your sample data uses `shelve` or `shelves` inconsistently.